# Storing Bfile takes more time than Blob in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have written this procedure to save a file as BFILE in oracle 10g Database

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_NEW_FIN_DETAILS1(S_USER_ID IN VARCHAR2,myfile IN BLOB)
AS

  l_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  FILEPATH VARCHAR2(20):='My_Folder'; 
  l_blob BLOB           :=NULL;
  l_blob_len INTEGER;
  l_pos      INTEGER := 1;
  --MYFILE_NAME VARCHAR2(250):='';
  MODFILENAME VARCHAR2(250):='';
  l_buffer RAW(32767);
  l_amount BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  ENTRYCODE VARCHAR2(10)  := '';
  STATUS VARCHAR2(10)  := '1';
  CNT NUMBER :=0;
  DOCUMENT_ID VARCHAR2(20)  := '';

   BEGIN  
    l_blob := myfile;
    l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);
    l_pos      := 1;

    MODFILENAME := 'test' || '.jpg';

    l_file     := UTL_FILE.fopen(FILEPATH,MODFILENAME,'wb', 32767);
    WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len
    LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
      UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
      l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    COMMIT;

 INSERT INTO temp_detail(S_DETAIL_ID,S_USER_ID,S_IMAGE,s_file)
VALUES(MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,S_USER_ID,null,bfilename(FILEPATH,MODFILENAME)); 
    commit;

END PROC_NEW_FIN_DETAILS1;
```

Earlier files were saved as BLOB in the Database itself using this query

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_DETAIL(S_DETAIL_ID,S_USER_ID,S_IMAGE,s_file) VALUES (MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?)
```

Techincally, BFILE is supposed to take less time than BLOB but in my case **BFILE take 3 time more time than BLOB**
What could be the reason for this??
I am new to writing Stored Procedures so please suggest me something to optimise this procedure

Answer (score 0):

I think the reasons can be in the wrong definitions: you simply compare the things with different nature.

Let's go through the code. Check my comments, I think this can be useful.

```
-- why do you do that? just use "myfile" instead of l_blob!
l_blob := myfile;

-- takes a bit of time, but of course cannot be avoided
l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);
l_pos      := 1;

MODFILENAME := 'test' || '.jpg';

l_file     := UTL_FILE.fopen(FILEPATH,MODFILENAME,'wb', 32767);

WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len
LOOP
  -- reading the values from current BLOB, should be quite fast but anyway takes time
  -- multiply this read-write operations execution time on the amount of iterations
  DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
  UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
  l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
COMMIT;
```

Now compare it to the insert of BLOB value:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_DETAIL(S_DETAIL_ID,S_USER_ID,S_IMAGE,s_file) VALUES (MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?);
```

Nothing. Just insert. And that's it. You should also understand that when you talk about a BLOB value, you say about the **locator**, which is only a reference to the real BLOB. That means when you insert a BLOB, the file content itself can be even not touched e.g. if this BLOB is already taken from database: [see documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm). In this case the reference will be saved only.

Of course, I have only the guesses here and I am not pretending of being 100% sure. But, at least, you can check these thoughts.

Comment: i made changes as per your suggestion and there is a marginal improvement but not much...and why is the time taken by PROCEDURE highly variable while time taken by direct insert (BLOB) fairly constant

Comment: where do you take BLOB from? is it saved in the database or you upload it somehow?

Comment: There is an applet that scans documents and I get an image file from the applet.

Comment: I think the problem is that your file is already BLOB. And you spend more time by converting it into BFILE. It does not mean BFILE is slower, simply the conversion needs time.

Comment: so is there any means to send file form java in bfile format to the procedure??

Comment: you can try to store it in java and send the filename only to Oracle side